# Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, path, npm-install, create-react-app

When I create React App, I counter an error(image below).
I use npm (v6.4), node (v8.9).

[image]

Can someone guide me?

Comment: Please, post some of your code in order to clarify your question.

Comment: i don't code yet, bro, i just only create react app

Comment: Can you try using node v10+ ?

Comment: i tried to use node v10.13 but it's still error :(

Answer (score 1):

Try using a higher version of node.

```
npm install -g npm@5.8.0
npm install -g npx@10.0.1
```

Also make sure that nvm path is added to your system variables.
Take a look at this: https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/144